# Highchart - Remove date form tooltip

Tags: highcharts

The question is simple: How can i remove the date from line tooltip in the graph?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the tooltip formatter ([documenation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter))

```
   tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the `tooltip.headFormat` to the empty string `''` which disables the tooltip header (which displays the data).

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.headerFormat